# Debug and inspect java core API?

Tags: java, debugging

I am trying to debug the java API class `PriorityQueue`in eclipse. I put the debug point on  line `queue.add(i)`, debugger goes inside `add > siftUpComparable` but i am not able to inspect/watch any variable value there . It says 'K can not be resolved to a variable'

```
    Queue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
    queue.add(i);
```

I am able to inspect/watch my custom class but not java api class . Is there any setting/configuration required in eclipse here ?

Comment: Do you really think you've found a bug in the `PriorityQueue` code?  Perhaps you actually have a bug in your code, which we could help you identify, if you posted that.

Comment: Is that message a syntax error? If you're trying to debug your code, the problems won't be with the Java API.

Comment: @AJNeufeld there is nobug anywhere. I just wanted to understand the implementation behind one of its method

Comment: The `Variables` tab will show you `this` and the arguments of the current function (`arg0`, `arg1`, ...).  If a local variable is used as an argument to another function, you could step into that function to see what the arguments current value is.  You can try using the `Expressions` tab evaluate your own expressions to track local variable values, but madness may quickly follow.  The only other options would be to find a debug-enabled version of the JDK ... or just read the source and try to determine what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a "Step Filters" setting you should use.

With Eclipse Mars, it would be in `Java > Debug > Step Filtering`.  Check all the `java.*` and `javax.*` filters to avoid stepping into those packages.

Then you can debug your application code without fear of stepping into the JRE code.

Comment: i am already able to step into `PriorityQueue` source code but not able to inspect or watch any variable inside it. I also tried the setting you suggested , but no impact